# c# - Unable to display results as string values

Tags: c#

I am working on a program in c# . There are 3 columns. Let's call them A,B and C. 
When any row in column B is unchecked but column A is checked, it should pop out a display warning message indicating which location id (rows) that has column A checked but column B unchecked.

I managed to create the display message to do this but instead of getting the location in the message box, it shows the values in :
`" DataGridView Column [0] Row[2] "`.

I figured I have to convert my List of `locationID` variable to convert to string but the results are the same.

Here is the code where ListLocationID is declared:

```
 List<string> listLocationID = new List<string>();
                List<int> listLocationIDIndex = new List<int>();


    for (int i = 0; i < this.dataGridLocationDetails.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
         if (((Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridLocationDetails.Rows[i].Cells["colViewPermission"].Value) == true)
                         && (Convert.ToBoolean(dataGridLocationDetails.Rows[i].Cells["colIssuePermission"].Value) == false)
                     ))
                    {
                            listLocationID.Add(dataGridLocationDetails.Rows[i].Cells["colLocationID"].ToString());

               listLocationIDIndex.Add(i);

     }


                        }

                bool isEmpty = true;
                if (listLocationID.Count > 0)
                    isEmpty = false;

        if(!isEmpty) 
        {
            string message = string.Format("The following Location ID has view permission but not issue permission:{0}  Do you wish to continue?", DisplayString(listLocationID));
        DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show(message, "WARNING", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

          if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)                       
         {                            
        for (int i = 0; i < listLocationIDIndex.Count; i++)                
        {

        }
         }                        
        else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)                       
         {                            
        return;                        
        }
        }
```

Here is part of the code to display the string:

```
 private string DisplayString(List<string> listLocationID)
        {
            String strSentence = string.Empty;
            for (int i = 0; i < listLocationID.Count; i++)
            {
                strSentence = strSentence + (listLocationID[i].ToString());

            }

            return strSentence;
        }
```

Note: listLocationID[i] is supposed to display the location name in message box. Instead it displayed the index column names.

Here is snapshot of the selection for checkbox:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Here is snapshot of the output i am getting:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Remove `.ToString()`. Additional you should use a `StringBuilder` to build your return string.

Comment: `listLocationID[i]` is already a string - so wherever you get that from (which you don't show) is not giving you the string you want

Comment: don't think you are passing the right input

Comment: The issue comes from where the parameter listLocationID is populated from the calling method. Post the code from there

Comment: Ok see my updated code

Comment: Im not sure the update would help here. Where is the method DisplayString is being called from? And what does the parameter passed to it contain? And how was these data assigned to that parameter?

Comment: @user743414 Originally, .ToString() wasn't implemented but it doesn't yield the results, so i tried adding that to it and still same results

Comment: @KingoftheNorth Did you see the updated code above?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part.

Comment: @KingoftheNorth That's weird, i was using your way  just now and it doesn't work. But right now it works. Weird. Anyway post up your solution and I'll mark it.

Comment: Moved comment to asnwer to allow better formatting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
listLocationID.Add(dataGridLocationDetails.Rows[i].Cells["colLocationID"].Value.ToString());
```

instead of

```
listLocationID.Add(dataGridLocationDetails.Rows[i].Cells["colLocationID"].ToString());
```

To allow a neat format as mentioned in comment:

use StringBuilder instead of string

```
StringBuilder strSentence = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < listLocationID.Count; i++)
{
     strSentence.Append(listLocationID[i]);
     strSentence.AppendLine();
}

return strSentence.ToString();
```

Comment: One more thing. In the display message box, the list goes like : Location1Location2Location3 etc .  I want it to display neatly like in a newline each location, how would i achieve that?

Comment: Use StringBuilder instead of string. Updated aswer

Answer (score 0):

Loop looks good. you dont have to convert to string explicitly as it is string array.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    List<string> listLocationID = new List<string>();
    listLocationID.Add("one");
    listLocationID.Add("two");
    listLocationID.Add("three");

     String strSentence = string.Empty;
     for (int i = 0; i < listLocationID.Count; i++)
        {
         strSentence = strSentence + (listLocationID[i]);
        }
        Console.Write(strSentence);
    }
}
```

you may try foreach as well

```
foreach (String locationID in listLocationID)
 {
  strSentence = strSentence + locationID ;
 }
```